# UK day two test switchover date?

Tags: uk, covid-19, vaccinations

Relevant tweet:

https://twitter.com/grantshapps/status/1438890006437847043?lang=en

> TRAVEL UPDATE: we’re making testing easier for travel  From Mon
> 4 Oct, if you’re fully vax you won’t need a pre-departure test before
> arrival into England from a non-red country and from later in Oct,
> will be able to replace the day 2 PCR test with a cheaper lateral
> flow.

I am travelling to a green list destination country from 5th to 8th October.

I am fully vaccinated (and have proof of this via the relevant NHS app).

As things currently stand, I think I need to book a day two PCR test on my return to the UK, which will cost at least £40. My understanding is that I don't need to book the test until I fill in the passenger locator form on my return to the UK, so I can potentially wait until then to book a test, although I might want to book a bit sooner if I need it to be posted to me.

(I also need to be tested on arrival in the destination country, but that's outside the scope of this question).

Is it safer to book a PCR test now, or should I wait a few more days and see if this requirement changes?

Comment: Maybe this should be closed since it would just be speculation. Anyway I would say it is very unlikely that the authorities will change the rules two times the same week.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ the bit concerns me re the timing is `...and from later in Oct,`

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some partial information. The Department for Transport responded to the tweet in the question:

https://twitter.com/transportgovuk/status/1438898310375411728?s=20

In that tweet, they posted this link:
https://www.gov.uk/government/news/new-system-for-international-travel

On that page is the following paragraph:

> From the end of October, eligible fully vaccinated passengers and
> those with an approved vaccine from a select group of non-red
> countries will be able to replace their day 2 test with a cheaper
> lateral flow test, reducing the cost of tests on arrival into England.
> The government wants to introduce this by the end of October, aiming
> to have it in place for when people return from half-term breaks.

That's still rather ambiguous but a bit of further research suggests that this is probably at some point during the week commencing 25th October.